# AutoKey - clipboard.get_selection() function fails on certain strings

Tags: python, encoding, python-2.7, special-characters, autokey

I've simplified my script so you can focus on the essence my problem.

In [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) (not AutoHotKey), I made a Hot-Key (shift-alt-T) that performs this script on any string I have highlighted (like in gedit for example -- but any other gui editor too).

```
strSelectedText = clipboard.get_selection()
keyboard.send_keys(" " + strSelectedText)
```

The script modifies the highlighted text and adds a space to the beginning of the string.

It works for most strings I highlight, but not this one:

```
* Copyright © 2008–2012 Lonnie Best. Licensed under the MIT License.
```

It works for this string:

```
* Add a Space 2.0.1
```

but not on this one:

```
* Add a Space 2.0.1 –
```

At the python command prompt, it has no problem any of those strings, yet the clipboard.get_selection() function seems to get corrupted by them.

I'm rather new to python scripting, so I'm not sure if this is an AutoKey bug, or if I'm missing some knowledge I should know about encoding/preparing strings in python.

Please help. I'm doing this on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-qt
```

Comment: Why do you keep adding the AutoHotKey tag, when you say questions are not about AutoHotKey?

Comment: Can you make a tag autokey for me? So I can associate the correct tag?

Comment: Hint: `$ charinfo '–'`
`U+2013 EN DASH`

Comment: Sure - I've just created the autokey tag, and added it to some obvious questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no keyboard key for the copyright symbol, or any non-ASCII character like the EN DASH in your third example. Your script code would have to somehow translate any non-ASCII Unicode characters into the appropriate keyboard sequences to generate them. Perhaps you could grab from the clipboard and use a clipboard function to paste the modified string back into your App.

Comment: The AutoKey clipboard works fine, but `keyboard.send_keys()` does not. Whenever you're not emitting control sequences, you should always put your text into the clipboard and then call `keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+v")` to paste the text into your application window. For phrases, select the `Paste  using Ctrl+V` option unless you have a specific reason not to. If your target window is a terminal, use ctrl+shift+v instead of ctrl+v because terminals use ctrl+v for something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the Python 3 implementation of `autokey` (special characters not passed through `keyboard.send_keys`). See [GitHub](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey/issues/49) for example.